# Sage Math browser interface not working

Tags: arch-linux, python

I wanted to try `Sage Math` as a free alternative to `MatLab`. I installed it from `AUR`, and it works in terminal, but I can't access it via the browser. I tried to Google it, but had no luck.

```
~> sage

┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Sage Version 6.3, Release Date: 2014-08-10                         │
│ Type "notebook()" for the browser-based notebook interface.        │
│ Type "help()" for help.                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
sage: notebook()
The notebook files are stored in: sage_notebook.sagenb
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                │
│ Open your web browser to http://localhost:8080 │
│                                                │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Executing twistd  --pidfile="sage_notebook.sagenb/sagenb.pid" -ny "sage_notebook.sagenb/twistedconf.tac"
/opt/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py:57: PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.
  _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)
2014-11-02 19:29:59+0100 [-] Log opened.
2014-11-02 19:29:59+0100 [-] twistd 13.2.0 (/opt/sage/local/bin/python 2.7.8) starting up.
2014-11-02 19:29:59+0100 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2014-11-02 19:29:59+0100 [-] QuietSite starting on 8080
2014-11-02 19:29:59+0100 [-] Starting factory <__builtin__.QuietSite instance at 0x7f4b7f7ab830>
```

It opens Chromium at `localhost:8080`, but it gives me `Connection Refused` error. I also tried this in Firefox, but with the same results.

There's some odd error, but it doesn't look like that's related.

I'm running the up-to-date Arch Linux 64bit.

I'll be grateful for any ideas to get this working.

Comment: Was it solved eventually? Does the provided answer solve it?

Comment: No, I gave up on this software long ago and used SciPy instead

Comment: That's sad. Sage is very powerful. Could you try this command : `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` and then open up the link http://localhost:8080/. Tell me if it's working or not. 
`

Comment: I've also added an alternative answer which you could also try.

Comment: Okay I'll try install it again, but it's really huge so it'll take me a few hours to download

Comment: So it "just works" now, not really sure what changed (but clearly a lot, since the Q is from november).

Comment: Glad to know that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue by editing `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost   my_hostname
::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost   my_hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this has got to do with some of your iptables (firewall) settings. You could try running sage server at a different port :

```
sage -c "notebook(port='9080')" &
```

Try different port numbers and see on which it is working.